# Prove that there exists $\varphi \in V'$ such that $\varphi(u) = 0$ for every $u \in U$ but $\varphi \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is finite dimensional. And $U$ a subspace of $V$ such $U \neq V$. Prove that there exists $\varphi \in V'$ such that $\varphi(u) = 0$ for every $u \in U$ but $\varphi \neq 0$

attempt: Here $V'$ is the dual space of $V$. Suppose dim$V$ = n. And let $U$ a subspace of $V$ such $U \neq V$. Then let $u_1,...,u_m$ be a basis of $U$. Then let $u_1,...,u_m,....,v_n$ be a basis of $V$. Then there are $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ in $V'$  such that $\varphi_j(u_m) = 1$ if $m = j$ or $\varphi_j(u_m) = 0 $  if $m \neq j$.

Thus we have $\varphi \in V'$ such that  for every $u \in U$ but $\varphi \neq 0$

Can someone please check this. And any feedback will be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What does " Then there are $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ in $V'$  such that $\varphi_j(u_m) = 1$ if $m = j$ or $\varphi_j(u_m) = 0 $  if $m \neq j$. " mean? In particular, that "or" ? And how do you prove the existence of those $\;\varphi_i\;$ ? Why not directly defining $\;\phi(u_i)=0\;,\;\phi(v_n)=1\;$ , extend by linearity this definition and that's all>?

Comment: I was just trying to use the definition that the dual basis of $v_1,..,v_n$ is the list  $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ of elements in $V'$ such that each $\varphi_j$ is the linear functional $V$. I wanted to start with a basis of U and then extend it to a basis of V , and then use the definiton

Comment: @Ma Do what I propose at the end of my past comment.

Comment: It is enough to define a linear transformation by it's action on the basis, since it will extend uniquely to the entire vector space. In  this case, it is simply  to take $\phi(u_i) = 0; \phi(v_i) = 1$ for $u_i$ being the basis of $U$ and $v_i$ the rest of the extended basis.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Exactly what I told him...but I can't say if he understands or wants to do that.

Comment: I don't know. I couldn't see your comment as my internet is slow.

Comment: So I can say , let $u_1,...,u_m$ be a basis of $U$, then we can extend it to a basis of $V$, so let $u_1,...,v_n$. Then $\varphi(u_i) = 0$ for $i = 1,...,m$ And $\varphi(v_i) = 1$ . What are the possible values of $i$? Are you using $\phi $ instead of $\varphi$?