# Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ with $W^0 \subset U^0$. Prove $U \subset W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ with $W^0 \subset U^0$. Prove $U \subset W$.

proof: Let $\varphi \in U$, then $\varphi(u) = 0$ for all $u \in U^0$. Because $W^0 \subset U^0$, then we have $\varphi(w) = 0$ for all $w \in U^0$, thus $\varphi \in W$, and so $U \subset W$.
Can someone please verify this? any feedback would help.
Thank you!

Comment: What is your notation $U^0$ mean? Also can you clarify the notation $\phi(u)$ for me?

Comment: $U^0$ is the annhilator of U , such that $U^0 = {\{\varphi \in V': \varphi(u) = 0 \forall u \in U}\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea points in the right direction, but you are missing things.

Let $u\in U$. If $u\not\in W$, then we can construct, [as in your other question today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976467/prove-that-there-exists-varphi-in-v-such-that-varphiu-0-for-every-u), an element $\varphi\in V'$ such that $\varphi(u)=1$ and $\varphi(w)=0$ for all $w\in W$. This last condition implies that $\varphi\in W^0\subset U^0$. But this is a contradiction, since $\varphi(u)=1$. The only other option is that $u\in W$. As we can do this for every $u\in U$, we get that $U\subset W$.

Comment: Why do you claim that the value of $u$ under $\phi$ is $\phi(u)=1?$

Comment: @azc: If $\phi(u)\ne1$, we construct $\phi_1=\phi/\phi(u)$ and then $\phi_1(u)=1$.